# Duplicated data coming from Firebase Firestore in React Native

Tags: react-native, google-cloud-firestore

I'm trying to load some data from my database in Firestore, but I don't why the variable is loading duplicated docs from it.

In Firestore, I've a collection with two elements, test1 and test2 as you can see in the screenshot below.

[image: Captura de Firestore]

I'm loading the full collection in my function seleccionarTest(), and I'd like to load var tests with the two docs (test1 and test2) that I will use later in a Touchable Flat List.

See the function:

```
export default function AsignarTest({route, navigation}){
console.log("Entrando en asignar test");
const {usuario} = route.params;

const [animacion, setAnimacion] = useState(true);
const [tests, setTests] = useState([]);

const db = firestore();

function seleccionarTests(){
    db.collection("test").get()
.then((querySnapshot) =>{       
    var i=0;
    querySnapshot.forEach((documentSnapshot)=>{
        tests.push({id:documentSnapshot.id, datos: documentSnapshot.data()});
    });
    setAnimacion(false);
    console.log(tests);
    return;
}).catch((error)=>{
    console.log(error);
    });
}

//Gestionamos cuando el usuario selecciona una peluqueria
const gestionarClick = (id)=>{
        //Todo
        console.log(id);
}

const p = seleccionarTests();

return(
    <View style={estiloGlobal.container}>
        <ActivityIndicator
            size="small"
            color = "#dd85be"
            animating = {animacion} />
        <View>
            <FlatList
                keyExtractor = {(item) => item.id}
                data={tests}
                renderItem= {({item})=> (
                    <TouchableOpacity
                        onPress={() =>{gestionarClick(item.id)}}>
                            <View style={estiloGlobal.lineaRecta}>
                                <View style={{paddingLeft: 10}}>
                                    <Text style= {estiloGlobal.botonTexto}>{item.id}</Text>
                                </View>
                            </View>
                    </TouchableOpacity>
                )} />
        </View>
    </View>
);
```

}

Unfortunately, as you can see in the next screenshot, my var in console.log has 4 documents, (test1, test2, test1, test2) and I can't understand why the docs are duplicated.

[image: Captura del console.log del array de tests]

Thanks for your comments!

Comment: Is your `seleccionarTests` function called more than once in your code somewhere else? If not what you could, in order to workaround this, clear the `tests` array when you enter the `seleccionarTests` function or on the promise resolve, that way you can guarantee that the array is empty before start pushing data.

Comment: Thanks, Ralemos. This workaround solved the issue. Still I need to understand why the function is called twice and this information is added duplicated to the variable.

Answer (score 1):

The reason why this is happening is either because somewhere else in your code the `seleccionarTests` function is being invoked a second time or that this data was actually junk data from a previous execution that was never cleaned in the array.

Either way in order to fix that you need to clear your array everytime you execute the function, doing something like this:

```
function seleccionarTests(){
    this.setState({tests: []});
    db.collection("test").get().then((querySnapshot) =>{       
        var i=0;
        querySnapshot.forEach((documentSnapshot)=>{
            tests.push({id:documentSnapshot.id, datos: documentSnapshot.data()});
        });
        setAnimacion(false);
        console.log(tests);
        return;
    }).catch((error)=>{
        console.log(error);
    });
}
```

**NOTE**: This should be always done as a best practice in a case like yours where you are populating an array with all the results of your collection to prevent duplicate data.

Comment: Thanks @ralemos. I think that the answer is not addressing the issue, and also it's not applicable, since functions don't have a this method to apply. I need to do some further investigation.

Comment: Aren't you using react? React does have the `this.setState()` method. Also, the part of the answer that explains why the array should cleared still apply.

Comment: I'm using React-native but not using classes, instead of functions and "this" refers to a class. Also, I think that the solution is more close to something like this https://linguinecode.com/post/how-to-avoid-multiple-re-renders-in-react-shouldcomponentupdate and the fact that the function is re-rendered so many times, but I can't understand why. I believe that setting the variable to empty is not fixing the issue on why is rendered twice.